# Auf etw. (dat) oder (akk) folgen?

Tags: preposition, dative, accusative

> Während eines Sturms verunglückte eine der Seilbahnkabinen. Vier Personen kamen ums Leben, rund dreißig wurden verletzt. *Auf den Unfall folgte eine dramatische Rettungsaktion*. Die Ursache wurde nach langen Ermittlungen als act of God deklariert.

Quelle: https://bit.ly/2lHcn8U

Aber ich habe auf dieser Seite etwas anderes gelesen. Ich meine, dass es " Auf **dem** Unfall sein sollte.

Quelle: https://bit.ly/2lBd97l

> ⟨etw. folgt (auf etw., einer Sache)⟩: Etw. kommt unmittelbar darauf, schließt sich an

Das bedeutet, dass es Dativ sein sollte. Ich habe mehrmals in Artikeln gesehen, dass es mit *Akk* benutzt wurde aber warum hat dann dieses Wörterbuch geschrieben, es muss mit *Dativ* verwendet werden?

Comment: "Auf dem Fuße folgen ..." wie unter diesem Link https://bit.ly/2lBd97l ersichtlich ist korrekt, wie auch "Auf den Unfall folgte ..." unter diesem Link https://bit.ly/2lHcn8U. Das heißt beides ist korrekt.

Comment: @otmarvonwien Schreib' das mal als Antwort. Der OP hat vermutlich das zitierte Wörterbuch nicht vollständig gelesen. _Auf **dem** Unfall_ hört sich für mich allerdings nicht korrekt an.

Comment: Wenn beides korrekt wären, sollten die beide Varianten in Wörterbüchern sein. Ich habe auch dieses Wort im "Langenscheidt" Wörterbuch nachgeschlagen und dort ist dies geschrieben : {etwas folgt (auf) etwas (Dat) : etwas kommt in der Reihenfolge od. ereignet sich zeitlich nach etwas.}

Comment: @Max Etwas / jemandem folgen ist ein Unterschied hinsichtlich einer zeitlichen Abfolge.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Auf dem Fuße folgen ..." wie unter diesem Link - [DWDS](http://bit.ly/2lBd97l) ersichtlich ist korrekt, wie auch "Auf den Unfall folgte ..." unter diesem Link - [Zeit Online](http://bit.ly/2lHcn8U).
Das heißt beides ist korrekt.

Von "Auf dem Unfall folgte ... " ist auf beiden Websites keine Rede. Diese Version wäre nämlich nicht korrekt.

- jemandem/etwas folgen (Dativ)
- auf etwas folgen (Akkusativ)

Comment: [auf] dem fuße folgen literally means you follow an object (a foot, although just a phrase); auf den unfall/notstand folgend ... means u have an event, and onto this event follows X

Answer (score 5):

Die Präposition *auf* ist eine der neun **Zwei-Wege-Präpositionen** *an, auf, hinter, neben, in, über, unter, vor, zwischen*, die entweder mit Akkusativ oder Dativ stehen können.

Das Verb *folgen* braucht eine Richtung, daher wird hier *auf* mit Akkusativ verwendet:

> Auf den Donnertag folgt der Freitag.
>
> Der Unfall folgt auf den Fahrfehler.

Alternativ kann man auch ein Dativobjekt verwenden.

> Dem Donnerstag folgt der Freitag.
>
> Der Unfall folgt dem Fahrfehler.

Der feste Ausdruck *auf dem Fuße folgen* enthält eine *zusätzliche* Information, auf welche Weise das Folgen geschieht.

> **Auf die durchzechte Nacht folgte** auf dem Fuße der schlimme Kater am Morgen.

Es wird so verwendet wie eine zusätzliche Ortsangabe mit *auf*:

> **Auf die Ankündigung** der Zugabe auf der Bühne **folgte** diese auf dem Fuße.

Nur *auf die Ankündigung* ist ein Präpositionalobjekt. Die anderen beiden *auf*-Ausdrücke sind adverbiale Bestimmungen.

Comment: Ich würde eher sagen, dass "auf dem Fuße" eine stehende Wendung ist, die so viel wie "sofort", "unmittelbar" etc. bedeutet. Ich stimme aber dem Ergebnis zu, dass "folgen auf" den Akkusativ erfordert, sofern ausgedrückt werden soll, dass die Substantivgruppe nach "auf" dem Subjekt zeitlich oder kausal vorausgeht.

Comment: Da gebe ich dir Recht.  
Ich entnahm dem Dudenartikel dass wenn es zeitlich verwendet wird, so nimmt man Akkusativ, und wenn eben nicht zeitlich, sondern eher räumlich - dann Dativ.  https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/folgen "auf dem Fuße" scheint eher tatsächlich eine Ausnahme zu sein. Eigentlich schade dass beide Wörterbücher so verwirrend sind.